# How to paraphrase and cite correctly a large thesis section with only one or two textbook sources?

Tags: citations, thesis, research-undergraduate, citation-style

**Context**
I have developed a program, which relies on a pretty common and well studied statistical method. It seems sensible to provide an extensive summary on the mathematical basis of this algorithm (intuitive introduction, general case, proof of convergence, ...), before going into the details of my actual work, were i have applied it on a specific problem. The focus of the work was the code development and analysis of the results.

I mainly used two textbooks for learning the theory. I believe they do a really good job in explaining the things, although I also use some other sources to get a different view on things, they practically contain everything I need for my section. There is basically a complete overlap in the concepts they explain, but with a different touch; for instance: (slightly) different notation, order and language.
With the reader of my thesis in mind, I want the best possible summary of the theory, therefore i´m trying to pick the best parts of both textbooks, and throw in some additional explanations or views, which i would have found helpful. "Sadly" the books are relatively concise, i.e. they use a bunch of technical terms which i´m more or less forced to "copy", and the explanations they provide are also of high quality. It is very hard for me to paraphrase them without making it worse.

**Problems**

1. How to paraphrase their contents without making it worse, while
2. citing them correctly.

**Current situation:**

1. Occasionally i can throw in my personal intuitive explanations, but apart from that, it´s basically just a bunch of technical terms glued together by normal words to guide the reader through equations. I don´t think that it would be sufficient to insert some synonyms and structure the sentences differently, but that´s more or less my current approach.
2. I wrote at the beginning of the section that the following is an excerpt of those two textbooks. Some minor occassional statements (one sentence) from other sources get quoted inside the text.

The current citation strategy has been motivated by this [related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/89379/a-large-part-of-my-masters-thesis-25-is-essentially-a-summary-of-one-book). The main difference I have is that I can hardly justify calling my text a "summary".

*Additional Context:*

- Direct quotation is basically out of question, because that would be a citation bigger than 5 pages.
- English is not my first language.
- Physics/Electrical Engineering background